# Module name __ not loaded with karma and requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, karma-runner, config

I have some repositories (A, B, C and TestRepo) all of them in local, i get karma to load spec files from repos A or B or C with a param (node script).

Now im trying to transpile the files cause some test are using `import` so i need babel. I configured babel as a preprocessor and it seems like it is working but know i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "builder" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

I tried all configs i know but still not working.

My karma.config.js is this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'test-main.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
}
```

My test-main.js for requirejs:

```
var allTestFiles = []
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '')
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule)
  }
})

require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base',
  deps: allTestFiles,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
})
```

And my node file, where i set karma files, preprocessor and so on base on the repository i got from params is this:

```
const cfg     = require('karma').config;
const stopper = require('karma').stopper;
const runner  = require('karma').runner;
const Server  = require('karma').Server;
const path    = require('path');

const REPOSITORY = process.argv[2] || '';
let karmaConfig = cfg.parseConfig(path.resolve('./karma.conf.js'), { port: 9876 } );
let BASE_PATH;

if (REPOSITORY !== 'all') {
    BASE_PATH = `/Users/fernando.delolmo/${REPOSITORY}`;
    karmaConfig.files.push({pattern: BASE_PATH + '/test/**/*.spec.js'});
    karmaConfig.files.push({pattern: BASE_PATH + '/src/**/*.js', included: true});
    karmaConfig.preprocessors[BASE_PATH + '/src/**/*.js']       = ['babel'];
    karmaConfig.preprocessors[BASE_PATH + '/test/**/*.spec.js'] = ['babel'];
    karmaConfig.exclude.push(BASE_PATH + '/node_modules/**/*.spec.js');   
} else {
    BASE_PATH = '/Users/fernando.delolmo/';
    karmaConfig.files.push({pattern: BASE_PATH + '**/test/**/*.spec.js'});
    karmaConfig.files.push({pattern: BASE_PATH + '**/src/**/*.js', included: true});
    karmaConfig.preprocessors[BASE_PATH + '**/src/**/*.js']       = ['babel'];
    karmaConfig.preprocessors[BASE_PATH + '**/test/**/*.spec.js'] = ['babel'];
    karmaConfig.exclude.push(BASE_PATH + '**/node_modules/**/*.spec.js');   
}

karmaConfig.basePath = BASE_PATH;

var server = new Server(karmaConfig, function(exitCode) {
  process.exit(exitCode);
});

server.start();

server.on('browser_start', function() {
    runner.run(karmaConfig, function(exitCode) {
        process.exit(exitCode);
    });
});

server.on('browser_complete', function() {
    stopper.stop(karmaConfig, function(exitCode) {
        process.exit(exitCode);
    });
});
```

Its my first time configuring karma, requirejs and babel all together so any help will be great :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay finally i got what's the problem here. Just in case some one get here finding any solution to problems like this.

If you want to run test with ES2015 modules with karma, you will use babel to transpile into CommonJS modules at first, good! but... you will get errors like export is undefined.. and.. why?? Simple, export/import still not supported on the browsers, this means you CAN'T run CommonJS modules on the browser without any module bundler (browersify or webpack).

So, keep this clear:

1st -> Babel only transpile your ES2015 code and test into CommonJS modules
2nd -> Webpack / Browersify get CommonJS modules and bundle them into a bundle.js and then you can run that on the browser with karma.